# historical market cap in json/csv for all coins?

Tags: api, currencies, market, historical-trade-data

I want to run a backtest on a "S&P 500" strategy for crypto investing. I'm looking for historical market cap data. Something like what coinmarketcap.com provides, but historically and in an easy to manipulate format.

coinmarketcap has snapshots, but I can't access those through the api, andhence would have to resolve to typing them down, not practical.

Any help would be appreciated